# How to use Couchbase N1QL query expansion in go SDK

Tags: go, couchbase, sql++

In the golang Couchbase SDK there are N1QL select examples documented with examples like this:

```
myQuery := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT airportname, city, country FROM `travel-sample` " +
        "WHERE type='airport' AND city=$1 ")
myParams = append(myParams, []interface{}{"Reno"})
rows, err := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(myQuery, myParams)
```

When I try it with the following, it doesn't find any records.

```
query := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE META().id LIKE 'TD:$1:%'")

rows, err := r.Bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(query, []interface{}{userid})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

But this does work and also works in the Couchbase console:

```
query := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE META().id LIKE 'TD:"+userid+":%'")
rows, err := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(query, nil)
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong here?

While the non-parametised option works I'd like to use the parametised one and mark it as a prepared statement with query.AdHoc(false)

Comment: Looking through the code for the client library and it appears that the substitution occurs on the server and not inside the client library.  Which makes sense.  And it would seem possibly that there might be a restriction as to where I can place the substitutions.  Would that be right?

Answer (score 0):

```
gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE META().id LIKE 'TD:$1:%'")
```

In above code your query parameter is include inside the quotes. query parameters inside string will not be replaced. So it is looking for document id "TD:$1:"

You should try this

```
gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE META().id LIKE 'TD:' || $1 || ':%' ")
```

OR

```
   gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE META().id LIKE $1")
    Pass $1  'TD:'+userid+':%'
```

OR

```
gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `bucket` WHERE META().id LIKE 'TD:"+userid+":%'")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try those when I get back to the project.  I tried without quotes at one point but nothing was found.  So I thought it needed them.  Second option may work so I will try that.